# Ruby-On-Rails Report creating via accessible ports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
host = Host.find(i) 
    a = host.open_ports

    openPorts = []

    a.split(",").each do |x|
        openPorts << x
    end
```

This is the set up were talking Ruby on Rails, so I set up my Ip address on `i`and grab all the open ports.String returned is then broken up via `","` and added to an array.

```
Finding.all.each do |p|
        openPorts.each do |y|
            if p.port == y
                Report.create(:port => p.port, 
                              :risk_rating => p.risk_rating, 
                              :finding => p.finding,
                              :implication => p.implication, 
                              :recommendation => p.recommendation)  
            end
        end
    end
```

Iterates through findings table in the database and checks if the ports match the open ports array we created above. If there is a match we create a new report, based on the given value from the finding table.

The problem is does not create a new report even if there is a match.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but I wanted to show you how to clean up the implementation a bit.

```
host = Host.find(i)
# I am assuming Finding#port is an Integer
# if Finding#port is a String then just remove the .map(&:to_i) portion 
open_ports = host.open_ports.split(",").map(&:to_i)
Finding.where(port: open_ports).each do |p|
  Report.create(:port => p.port, 
                :risk_rating => p.risk_rating, 
                :finding => p.finding,
                :implication => p.implication, 
                :recommendation => p.recommendation)  
end
```

Lets start at the top

`String#split` returns an Array so no need to push it into a new one. It does however create an Array of Strings so if you need integers `#map(&:to_i)` will do this for you. I am assuming this is the current issue which is comparison of a string with integer for example `"80" == 80 #=> false`

Next rather than loop through all the `Finding`s why not just pull out the one's with matching ports? `Finding.where(port: open_ports)` this will generate a query like `SELECT findings.* FROM findings where findings.port IN (YOUR_OPEN_PORTS_ARRAY)`

Then we just create the reports from this limited list instead of the loop through all `Finding`s and then a loop through `open_ports` as well.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, got sorted after a re-factor but your answer is close to what was changed ( some other minor silly mistakes) so Thank you.